# Sending an email template on request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer

**how to choose a template for sending an email?** 

*I get a request for example: `reset_password`. But I also have registrations (`signup`).

How do I send the letter that I need on request?*

*I want to* `http://localhost:3000/sendmail?apiKey=test&type=reset_password`

reset_password: `http://localhost:3000/sendmail?apiKey=test&type=reset_password`
signup: `http://localhost:3000/sendmail?apiKey=test&type=signup`
if it is a registration, a registration or password reset letter
**How do I process this? The request sends the template that you need**

```
const transporter = require("./transporter");
const ejs = require('ejs')
const path = require('path')


const mailer = async (type, to) => {
      what handler?
     const reset_password = path.join(__dirname, "../reset_password.ejs"),
     const signup = path.join(__dirname, "../signup.ejs")

    const data = await ejs.renderFile(reset_password,signup { to });


    const mainOptions = {
      from: 'test', 
      to: to,
      text: "Hello world?",
      subject: 'dw', 
      html: data
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mainOptions) 
  };


module.exports = mailer;
```

**How do I make it so:
If a "reset_password" request comes, an email with a different email template is sent, if it is "signup" an email with a different template is sent.**
*in the type request comes reset_password or signup
I don't understand how to make it so that each request would have different email templates ps: different type. and different letter templates*

Comment: This is like your third account created to ask this question  add more information like the template for the reset password and signup with the routes you passing them

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril. Ohhh no. Two question.Account one.
`const email = async (req, res) => {
  const { type, to } = req.query;
}`. There I simply process the request and send it to the mailer `mailer(type, to)`

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril, I don't understand how I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - fix your mailer code

```
const mailer = async (type, to) => {
     const template = path.join(__dirname, `../${type}.ejs`)

    const data = await ejs.renderFile(template, { to });


    const mainOptions = {
      from: 'test', 
      to: to,
      text: "Hello world?",
      subject: 'dw', 
      html: data
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mainOptions) 
  };
```

Then , ensure to send to the mailer function the type parameter (first one) using

```
const { apiKey, type } = req.query
const email = '...' // todo: grab user email
mailer(type, email)
```